# Unloading VSTO COM Excel AddIn is not releasing memory occupied

Tags: memory-leaks, vsto

I have created a COM AddIn for Excel using VSTO, I'm unloading AddIn but somehow excel process is not releasing  memory occupied during AddIn initialization.

Calling Dispose() function on .NET object then making it null, then calling GC.Collect(), GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() but it is releasing small amount of memory for that particular object but not for common memory consumed by Excel process during AddIn initialization, even I've used following options.

Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(worksheet);

Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook);

Even if I close workbook but memory associated with excel is not releasing. It appears that Excel process need to flush memory but not doing.

Any suggestion is welcome!!

Comment: How has the Add-in been deployed, or are you getting this while running through Visual Studio?

Comment: Deployment is using Visaul Studio Deployment (.msi and setup) files, Right now it is the issue with memory release as I'm running through Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you have a global variable being used across the project?
If yes, look whether this is being properly disposed or not...

Comment: Global variables are used at AddIn levels like Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook etc..

Comment: In my case, I was using Appversion to check the current version of office. Also, this was being used to update the tab text(uppercase-2013 or lowercase-2010) using an if-else loop in designer.cs file...Make sure you are not having any such logic in designer.cs file for the ribbon...

Comment: Thanks Gopal!!Earlier I was using ribbon but now I've removed ribbon..

Comment: Thanks Gopal!! It appears that Third Party Lightning WPF Charts are leaking memory even though you release chart object but addin is not releasing, contacted Lightning Chart team and they assured to look into this.